# Instance property 'party_id' is not defined for type '<>f__AnonymousType2`6

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-expressions

i build one helper method for filter column.

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static IQueryable<T> FilterForColumn<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, string colName, string searchText)
    {
        if (colName != null && searchText != null)
        {
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "m");
            var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, colName);
            System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression searchExpression = null;
            System.Reflection.MethodInfo containsMethod = null;
            // this must be of type Expression to accept different type of expressions
            // i.e. BinaryExpression, MethodCallExpression, ...
            System.Linq.Expressions.Expression body = null;
            Expression ex1 = null;
            Expression ex2 = null;
            Expression converted = null;
            switch (colName)
            {
                case "party_id":
                case "type_id":
                case "status_id":
                case "category_id":
                    Int32 _int = Convert.ToInt32(searchText);
                    searchExpression = Expression.Constant(_int);
                    containsMethod = typeof(Int32).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(Int32) });
                    body = Expression.Call(propertyExpression, containsMethod, searchExpression);
                    break;
                case "country_id":
                case "state_id":
                    Int32? _int1 = Convert.ToInt32(searchText);
                    searchExpression = Expression.Constant(_int1);
                    converted = Expression.Convert(searchExpression, typeof(object));
                    containsMethod = typeof(Int32?).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(Int32?) });
                    body = Expression.Call(propertyExpression, containsMethod, converted);
                    break;
                // section for DateTime? properties
                case "PublishDate":
                case "Birth_date":
                case "Anniversary_date":
                case "Profile_Updated_datetime":
                case "CompletedOn":
                    DateTime currentDate = DateTime.ParseExact(searchText, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
                    DateTime nextDate = currentDate.AddDays(1);
                    ex1 = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(propertyExpression, Expression.Constant(currentDate, typeof(DateTime?)));
                    ex2 = Expression.LessThan(propertyExpression, Expression.Constant(nextDate, typeof(DateTime?)));
                    body = Expression.AndAlso(ex1, ex2);
                    break;
                // section for DateTime properties
                case "Created_date":
                case "Register_Date":
                    DateTime currentDate1 = DateTime.ParseExact(searchText, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
                    DateTime nextDate1 = currentDate1.AddDays(1);
                    ex1 = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(propertyExpression, Expression.Constant(currentDate1));
                    ex2 = Expression.LessThan(propertyExpression, Expression.Constant(nextDate1));
                    body = Expression.AndAlso(ex1, ex2);
                    break;
                default:
                    searchExpression = Expression.Constant(searchText);
                    containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
                    body = Expression.Call(propertyExpression, containsMethod, searchExpression);
                    break;
            }
            var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, new[] { parameter });
            return queryable.Where(predicate);
        }
        else
        {
            return queryable;
        }
    }
}
```

now this code for which i'm passing values to FilterColumn:

```
protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            using(DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
            {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            if (DDL_Column_List.SelectedItem.Value != "-1" && txtsearch.Text.Trim() != "")
            {
                switch (DDL_Column_List.SelectedItem.Text.ToString())
                {
                    case "Ticket ID":
                        Session["ColumnName"] = "Ref_no";
                        Session["SearchText"] = txtsearch.Text.Trim();
                        break;
                    case "Name":
                        Session["ColumnName"] = "party_id";
                        Session["SearchText"] = db.Parties.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(txtsearch.Text.Trim())).Select(p => p.Id).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
                        break;
                    case "Status":
                        Session["ColumnName"] = "status_id";
                        Session["SearchText"] = db.Status.Where(s => s.StatusName.Contains(txtsearch.Text.Trim())).Select(s => s.Id).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
                        break;
                    case "Category":
                        Session["ColumnName"] = "category_id";
                        Session["SearchText"] = db.Categories.Where(c => c.category_name.Contains(txtsearch.Text.Trim())).Select(c=>c.Id).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
                        break;
                    case "Date Created":
                        Session["ColumnName"] = "Created_date";
                        Session["SearchText"] = txtsearch.Text.Trim();
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Session["SearchText"] = null;
                Session["ColumnName"] = null;
            }
            this.FillGrid((String)Session["StartAlpha"] ?? null, (String)Session["GroupByENTYPE"] ?? null, (List<int?>)Session["GroupByCategory"] ?? null, (List<int?>)Session["GroupByStatus"] ?? null, (String)Session["ColumnName"] ?? null, (String)Session["SearchText"] ?? null);
            UpdatePanel5.Update();
            }
        }
    }
```

here is my query that was i want to filter :

```
 var  enquiry = db.EnquiryHistories.Where(i => i.enttype_id.Equals(entrytypeid) && GroupByCategory.Contains(i.category_id) && GroupByStatus.Contains(i.status_id) && (i.ForwardTo.Equals(userid) || i.AttendBy.Equals(userid))).OrderByDescending(i => i.Activity_start_datetime).Select(i => new
                           {
                               Ref_no = i.Ref_no,
                               Name = db.Parties.Where(p => p.Id.Equals(i.party_id)).Select(p => p.Name).SingleOrDefault(),
                               StatusName = db.Status.Where(s => s.Id.Equals(i.status_id)).Select(s => s.StatusName).SingleOrDefault(),
                               CategoryName = db.Categories.Where(c => c.Id.Equals(i.category_id)).Select(c => c.category_name).SingleOrDefault(),
                               IsUregent = i.IsUregent,
                               Created_date = i.Activity_start_datetime
                           }).FilterForColumn(ColumnName, SearchText).ToList();
```

this is my tabel schema :

```
+--------------------------+---------------+
|  Column Name             | Data Type     |
+--------------------------+---------------+
| Ref_no                   | char(14)      |
| party_id                 | int           |
| category_id              | int           |
| callFor                  | text          |
| callBy                   | text          |
| AttendBy                 | char(14)      |
| status_id                | int           |
| status                   | text          |
| ForwardTo                | char(14)      |
| ForwardFor               | int           |
| ReplyDate                | datetime      |
| Remark                   | text          |
| enttype_id               | int           |
| paystatus_id             | int           |
| paydate                  | datetime      |
| payperson                | varchar(50)   |
| paymathod                | varchar(50)   |
| chqno                    | varchar(50)   |
| bankname                 | varchar(100)  |
| paymentamount            | int           |
| IsUregent                | bit           |
| IsRead                   | bit           |
| IsReplied                | bit           |
| IsDisplay                | bit           |
| Activity_start_datetime  | smalldatetime |
| Activity_expire_datetime | smalldatetime |
+--------------------------+---------------+
```

how ever in case of party_id i fount this error :

```
Server Error in '/CRM' Application.

Instance property 'party_id' is not defined for type '<>f__AnonymousType2`6[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Boolean,System.DateTime]'

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Instance property 'party_id' is not defined for type '<>f__AnonymousType2`6[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Boolean,System.DateTime]'

Source Error: 


Line 23:         {
Line 24:             var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "m");
Line 25:             var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, colName);
Line 26:             System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression searchExpression = null;
Line 27:             System.Reflection.MethodInfo containsMethod = null;

Source File: f:\CRM\App_Code\Helper.cs    Line: 25 

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentException: Instance property 'party_id' is not defined for type '<>f__AnonymousType2`6[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Boolean,System.DateTime]']
   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(Expression expression, String propertyName) +4189559
   Helper.FilterForColumn(IQueryable`1 queryable, String colName, String searchText) in f:\CRM\App_Code\Helper.cs:25
   Staff_Ticket_History.FillGrid(String StartAlpha, String GroupByENTYPE, List`1 GroupByCategory, List`1 GroupByStatus, String ColumnName, String SearchText) in f:\CRM\Staff\Ticket_History.aspx.cs:347
   Staff_Ticket_History.btnsearch_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in f:\CRM\Staff\Ticket_History.aspx.cs:597
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +176
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

Comment: Okay: my downvote is because the exception is telling you what's wrong, and your question demonstrates no effort in trying to understand what the exception's telling you. If you understood the exception, you wouldn't have asked this question, but if there's something about it that you're having trouble understanding, and your question explains what part of it you don't get, *that* could be a good question.

Comment: The error message says it all the object you are hvaing has no property called "party_id" and thus when you try to access it you get an error

Comment: another instance of shunnig non native-english speakers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't downvote you, but I assume you got a downvote because you have given us way too much information to dig through and your lines are way too long, requiring lots of horizontal scrolling. You should pare it down to the minimum set of code that can reproduce the issue.

It looks like you are calling `FilterForColumn` with a column name of "party_id", but this is immediately after a `Select()` that produces an `IQueryable` of an anonymous type with properties named

- Ref_no
- Name
- StatusName
- CategoryName
- IsUregent [sic]
- Created_date

In other words, no property named `party_id`. In fact, it looks like most of the column names in your `case` statement are not present in this anonymous type.

I'm not sure I can tell you exactly how to fix this, but the simple answer might be to include all the needed column values in the anonymous type you are constructing there.

Comment: ok.i understand what exactly you want to tell. but i have party_id as int field of this table. look my update question.